# Running make4ht + polyglossia under MiKTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex, windows, make4ht

I'm running a document which compiles to HTML using make4ht + LuaLaTeX.

When testing both on Ubuntu, it works flawlessly, but when the same document is ran on Windows 10 with MiKTeX, I get a bunch of `"Unsupported font"` errors.

While making a minimal example, I realized this only happened when I imported the `polyglossia` package.

A minimal example of such document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Compiled through (using v0.3e from MikTeX):

```
$ make4ht -l document.tex
```

Gives:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: prueba.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
 restricted system commands enabled.
Unsupported font        [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
 restricted system commands enabled.
Unsupported font        [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
 restricted system commands enabled.
Unsupported font        [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;

# (a bunch of debugging from the document iself)

----------------------------------------------------
--- error --- Can't find/open file `[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;.tfm'
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 1
```

This is a fresh installation of Windows 10 running latest MiKTeX, installed directly from their website. The command was run under PowerShell. The full output of make4ht can be found on [this](https://gist.github.com/agucova/9698075b951e02562736be8bd18448d4) gist.

I've tried changing fonts with no luck, as well as playing with MiKTex settings.

Comment: the tex4ht version in miktex seems to lag behind the one in texlive (where your example works). Ask for an update in the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: It seems that this issue is fixed now, Miktex's files for TeX4ht were updated recently.